# JavaScript, loop objects with different number of pairs key-value

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, object, key

Making a simple bar chart. Every data that will be displayed has this structure:

```
var data = [{
    "id": "myId",
    "fillColor": "myColor"
},
{
    "id": "myId2",
    "fillColor": "myColor"
},
...]
```

Now, for each column that will be shown:

```
var columns = [{
    "category": "My category", //what will be displayed as a label
    "myId": 200 //a value to fill
},
{
    "category": "Me second category",
    "myId2": 300
},
...]
```

While displaying a simple bar, I just loop through the array, get the id from "data" and display the value from "columns".

```
for(var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    id = data[i]["id"];
    //display the value with 
    value = columns[i][id]; //and display it later
}
```

All this is working perfectly.

Now, I needed to do a stacked bar, so at first, I thought of adding the "id" from data to column with value, for example in the first column:

```
{
    "category": "My category",
    "myId": 200,
    "myId2": 150
},{
    "category": "My category2",
    "myId2": 300
}
```

And here is where I get stuck. I don't know how to loop through key-values from objects with different numbers of pairs key-value. Javascript doesn't have a `foreach()` function as can be PHP.

Hope this is more clarifying.

Comment: You can implement json here. It will give key value pair

Comment: `to create some objects inside an array` - How? With what data?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you asking how to get the values from each object? And do what with them? You just need to loop through the array and then for each object loop through the key/value pairs.

Comment: @thefourtheye Making a very simple stacked bar chart. I have already a bar chart with just one value to show, but when was time to try to implement stacked values I reached that point that I need to go through many key-value. I know there are many charts out there, but I need some special visual effects that needs to be added, and I gone to do it for my self, success till stacked.

Comment: @Andy added a clarification, hope it's a bit more clear

Comment: Please post your expected output, your question is not still clear

Comment: Did you want to loop thru and display key values for each array item?

Comment: Is this what you wanted [http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/4h6dee0r/](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/4h6dee0r/)

Comment: @LShetty yes, I think is that! Need to go through all those. Thanks! If you can post the answer I'll accept it as the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to loop through key-values from objects with different numbers of pairs key-value. Javascript doesn't have a foreach() function as can be PHP.

So, Javascript does have a `forEach` and below is how you loop thru to get key values from an object.

```
var myObj = [{
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2"
}, {
    "key1": "value1",
    "key2": "value2",
    "key3": "value3"
}];

myObj.forEach(function(val, index) {
    for (var key in val) {
        alert ("Array item: " + (index+1) + " Key: " + key + " Value: " + val[key]);
    }
});
```

For all browsers including <=IE8

```
for (var i=0, j=myObj.length; i<j; i++) {
    for (var key in myObj[i]) {
        alert ("Array item: " + (i+1) + " Key: " + key + " Value: " + myObj[i][key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, that forEach loop is not working on IE8 :( chrome, firefox and safari working well, but not for IE8. Any other way for that tricky browser?

Comment: Sure, the good old [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) :)